# Filtering ListView by clicking button from Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch data (Tasks) from Firebase that meets a query when a button is clicked. I can fetch all data (Tasks) but when I click on the button to fetch the filtered data I don't receive the expected results.

I have set the non-filtered adapter to be cleared when I click on the button and set the filteredAdapter with no results.

Am I close to getting this right?

**Database structure**

[image]

**My firebase query**

```
final Query statusQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Store 01").child("Task List")
            .orderByChild("Status")
            .equalTo("Complete");
```

**Code for fetching filtered data**

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> filterAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.tasks_layout, R.id.textTask, listTask);
    this.dbTasks.setAdapter(filterAdapter);

    statusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           statusQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                       //adding the key to an Arraylist to be referenced when deleting records
                       filteredTasks.add(ds.getKey());
                       String name = ds.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
                       String date = ds.child("Date").getValue(String.class);
                       String assigned = ds.child("Assigned to").getValue(String.class);
                       String type = ds.child("Type").getValue(String.class);

                       queryTask.add(name  + "\n" + date + "\n" + assigned + "\n" + type);
                Log.d("TAG", name);
                   }//for
                   task_list.this.dbTasks.setAdapter(filterAdapter);
                   arrayAdapter.clear();
                   arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               }//onDataChange

               @Override
               public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

               }//OnCancelled
           });
        }//OnClick
    });
```

**Code for fetching non-filtered data**

```
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        //Searching the database and adding each task to list
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //adding the key to an Arraylist to be referenced when deleting records
                tasks.add(ds.getKey());
                String name = ds.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
                String date = ds.child("Date").getValue(String.class);
                String assigned = ds.child("Assigned to").getValue(String.class);
                String type = ds.child("Type").getValue(String.class);

                listTask.add(name  + "\n" + date + "\n" + assigned + "\n" + type);
                Log.d("TAG", name);
            }//for
            task_list.this.dbTasks.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }//onDataChange

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }//OnCancelled
    };
    database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: DB structure added - thanks

Comment: You are passing to the adapter the `listTask` and from the database you are adding the items to the `filteredTasks`. Which is correct?

Comment: Hi Alex, I hadn't considered passing the correct List Array to my adapter I passed the queryTask Array instead of listTask to the adapter and that work now as expected. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> filterAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.tasks_layout, R.id.textTask, listTask);
this.dbTasks.setAdapter(filterAdapter);
```

The new array adapter is pointing to the wrong arrayList "listTask" I pointed it to "queryTask" and this fixed the issue.

```
filterAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.tasks_layout, R.id.textTask, queryTask);
```